# Java jdbc java.sql.SQLException: General error at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

estoy creando un metodo para añadir un empleado a la base de datos, concretamente a la tabla empleado, donde uno de sus campos es la sucursal a la que pertenece. En el caso que la sucursal no exista debo insertarla en la tabla sucursal.

El problema es que me salta un general error.

El codigo de los metodos que intervienen es:

```
public void aniadirEmpleado(Empleado arg0) throws ExcepcionDeAplicacion {
    String sql1 = "Insert into sucursal values (?,?,?,?)";
    String sql2 = "Insert into empleado values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Connection con =null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    
    try{
        con= DriverManager.getConnection(getPropiedad("url"));
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        
        if(existeGenerico("sucursal","ID_SUCURSAL",arg0.getSucursal().getId())){
            
            stm=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            
            stm.setString(1, arg0.getId());
            stm.setString(2, arg0.getNombre());
            stm.setString(3, arg0.getApellidos());
            stm.setString(4, arg0.getTrabajo());
            String sexo= (new StringBuffer().append(arg0.getSexo())).toString();
            stm.setString(5, sexo);
            stm.setDate(6, calendarToDate(arg0.getFechaNacimiento()));
            stm.setDouble(7, arg0.getSalario());
            stm.setString(8, arg0.getSucursal().getId());
            
            stm.executeUpdate();

            
        }else{
            
            stm=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            stm.setString(1, arg0.getSucursal().getId());
            stm.setString(2, "");
            stm.setString(3, "");
            stm.setString(4, "");
            stm.executeUpdate();
            
            stm=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            stm.setString(1, arg0.getId());
            stm.setString(2, arg0.getNombre());
            stm.setString(3, arg0.getApellidos());
            stm.setString(4, arg0.getTrabajo());
            String sexo= (new StringBuffer().append(arg0.getSexo())).toString();
            stm.setString(5, sexo);
            stm.setDate(6, calendarToDate(arg0.getFechaNacimiento()));
            stm.setDouble(7, arg0.getSalario());
            stm.setString(8, arg0.getSucursal().getId());
            stm.executeUpdate();
            
            
            
        }
        
        stm.close();
        
        con.commit();
        
        
        
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try{
        if(con != null){
            con.rollback();
        }
        }catch(SQLException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new ExcepcionDeAplicacion();
    }
    finally{
        try{
        if(con != null){
            con.close();
        }
        }catch (SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExcepcionDeAplicacion();
        }
    }
    
}

public static Date calendarToDate(Calendar c){
    Date d = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    return d;
}
public boolean existeGenerico(String tabla, String nombreCampo, String valorCampo){
    String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM " + tabla + " WHERE ? = ?";

    Connection con =null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    boolean existe = false;

    
    try{
        con= DriverManager.getConnection(getPropiedad("url"));
        
        stm=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        stm.setString(1, nombreCampo);
        stm.setString(2, valorCampo);

        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
        
        if(rs.next()){
            existe = true;
        }else{
            existe=false;
        }
        

        rs.close();
        stm.close();

        
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    { 
        try
        { 
            if(con != null) con.close(); 
        } 
        catch(SQLException e2) 
        { 
            e2.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    
    return existe;
}
```

El error que me salta es:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: General error  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
> at sol.GestorBD.aniadirEmpleado(GestorBD.java:334)
> ```

Con otros metodos la bd funciona correctamente asi que es problema de conexion.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cual es la línea 334 de GestorBD.java?

Comment: Ed1: en el metodo existeGenerico he cambiado la primera ? por el nombre del campo directamente.

Comment: la linea 334 es el primer esecuteUpdate dentro del else pero con el cambio que he comentado me da el error ahora en la linea 324, que es el executeUpdate de dentro del if

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 posibles causas: 1ª. Verifica que realmente en cada `stm.set...` estás enviando el tipo de dato correcto, sobre todo en los campos de tipo `Date` 2ª. Yo pondría en los insert los nombres de cada columna de manera explícita: `INSERT INTO tabla (columna1, columna 2...) VALUES (?,?)` Por otra parte, si mal no recuerdo los nombres de columna no se pasan en parámetro al statement (ni hace falta) ya que la idea de las consultas preparadas es justamente separar los datos de la sentencia SQL. Si quieres más control puedes tener un método de validación de nombres de tablas/columnas.

Comment: Por ejemplo aquí: `stm.setString(1, arg0.getId());` ¿el getId() obtiene una cadena o bien un número?

Comment: Tengo una sospecha que podría ser el problema (lamentablemente "General error" muchas veces requiere buenas sospechas). Podrías compartir los `CREATE` statements para tus tablas?

Comment: Ese error lo saca Access cuando se está intentando insertar un registro en una tabla y ya existe en dicha tabla otro registro con la misma clave primaria.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo con el Ed1 que he puesto estaba bien lo que pasaba que insertaba un empleado con un test y al volver a ejecutar el test me daba el problema porque ya estaba insertado.